# Declaring and Initializing Arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain to me why this works:

```
Dim myArr As Variant `or, myArr()`
myArr = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Dan", "Mark", "Tom")
```

And this doesn't:

```
Dim myArr As String
myArr = Array("Brian", "Steve", "Dan", "Mark", "Tom")
```

I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Because the `Array` statement returns a `Variant`. Even if you declared a string array (`Dim myArr() as String`) it wouldn't work.

Comment: Consider `Dim myArr() as String` and then `myArr = Split("Brian,Steve,Dan,Mark,Tom", ",")`.

Comment: That works nicely, too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the function `Array` returns a `Variant`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx